# Backbone View returns as a string: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }

Tags: backbone.js, view

Good day.
Have next problem.
from Router i request view but i returned as "function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }"
And i have no access to methods.

router.js:

```
    // Filename: router.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/page/pageView'
], function($, _, Backbone, PageView){

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "index",
            "page": "page"
        },

        index: function() {

            //console.log(PageView);
            PageView;
        },

        page: function() {
            alert("page");//welcomeViewInstance.render();
        }
    });

    initialize = function(){

        var appRouterInstance = new AppRouter();

        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

View.js:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/page/page.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, pageTemplate){

    var pageView = Backbone.View.extend({
       test: "test"

    });

    return pageView;
});
```

I stuck with it.
How i can manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of PageView

```
var view = new PageView();
```

inside your *index()* method or return the instance directly from *View.js* (depends how do you plan to build your app and what behaviour do you expect).